# Play Framework / Ebean save/update/delete method confusion

Tags: playframework-2.0, ebean

Given an instance of play.db.ebean.Model, what is the difference between calling Ebean.save(modelInstance) and modelInstance.save()?

Both result in the model being correctly saved to the database, however calling Ebean.save() does not result in the model's save() method being called.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever needed to save an entirely new bean to the database (therefore doesn't have an instance) you would be forced to call the `Ebean.save(bean)` method.